# ReactJS -Throw Submission Error with axios response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, redux-form

I am having understanding problem to make my code work properly. Basically I want to validate a data from server, which on validation doesn't throw error but give proper response where I need to handle the response and throw Submission Error to show validation error with redux-form.

Following is my code..

```
onFormSubmit = (values) =>{
    this.setState({loading:true});
    this.props.validateEmailFromServer(this.props.session,values,(response)=>{
      if(response.success === 2){
        throw new SubmissionError({email:'Email already Taken', _error:'Failed'});
      }
    });
}
```

Action is defined as follows

```
export function validateEmailFromServer(session,values,callback){

  var url='API_URL';
  var response = axios.get(url, null, 
                           getHeaders(session));
  return (dispatch) => {
    response.then(({data}) => {
      if(data.resource.length>0){
        callback({success: 2,message:'Email id is not available!'});
      }else{
        callback({success: 1,message:'Email is available!'});
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      callback({success: 0, message: error});
    });
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is when I am throwing the **Submission Error** when callback is called on **onFormSubmit** function it is calling the error block of axios automatically, I am not able to get out of it..

I need help to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for your pointers, I managed to get the solution, I changed the action and directly calling the axios in onFormSubmit function as follows, it works..

```
onFormSubmit = (values) =>{
    var getUrl = 'APIURL';
    return axios.get(getUrl,getHeaders(this.props.session))
            .then(function({data}) {
              if(data.resource.length>0)
                throw new Error("ValidationError");
              else{
                console.log("Proceed");
              }
            }).catch((err) =>{
                if(err.message === 'ValidationError')
                 throw new SubmissionError({email:'Email already Taken', _error:'Failed'});
            });
}
```

Hope this helps people who are trying to find similar solution.

Thanks for help.. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `callback` invocation in a regular `try...catch`, otherwise unhandled `SubmissionError` will naturally result in rejection of the whole `response` Promise.

```
export function validateEmailFromServer(session,values,callback){

  var url='API_URL';
  var response = axios.get(url, null, 
                           getHeaders(session));
  return (dispatch) => {
    response.then(({data}) => {
      try {
        if(data.resource.length>0){
          callback({success: 2,message:'Email id is not available!'});
        }else{
          callback({success: 1,message:'Email is available!'});
        }
      } catch(ex) {
        // do something
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      callback({success: 0, message: error});
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, do you mean to wrap the Submission error in try catch block?

Comment: The whole logic is a bit messy here, but I've updated my answer with what I mean. I'd recommend to rethink the logic flow though.

Comment: I don't see a need to `try/catch` here, this is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Lol... I'd say the whole thing is anti-pattern. But you need a `try..catch` there if you want to intercept `SubmissionError` before it makes into the `.catch` block of the `axios` response.

Comment: Adding try/catch doesn't solve anything, same thing is happening just the inner catch block is been called... Logic is straight forward.. may be I should remove callback and use something else?

Comment: Inner catch block is meant to catch the error and gives you opportunity to handle it somehow, dispatch something meaningful maybe. But yes you should rework the whole thing. Maybe figure out the result of the axios request first and then invoke callback. You have them intertwined at the moment.

Comment: @jayarjo Thanks for help, I changed the code removed callback etc.. it is working for me now, check my answer. Thanks for Help.. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

When using promises, and you have a `.catch` block, it will not trigger additional `.catch` blocks in the chain unless you re-throw the error.

I suspect this may be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trowing an error when an email is already taken, handle it with something like notifyEmailTaken(). You are throwing and error so, it is getting caught by your catch statement (that is my guess).

Good luck!

Comment: Yes that's right, but requirement is to show default redux-form error, that's why I am using Submission Error, which works well without Promise.

Comment: Ok, have you tried throwing the error inside the promise? Right where you determine the email is not available... does that work?

Comment: Do you have access to the to the API / backend? You could get "email is already taken" to return as an error allowing you to handle it within your catch statement... no?

Comment: Wait... you could chain another .catch() to the existing catch. You handle the "email is taken" error on the first one and handle any others on the second... give that a try!

Comment: Api can't throw error until it is a proper error, anyways I managed to solve the issue, thanks for help, I have posted my answer.. Cheers.